# Twitter Bootstrap - Dropdown height too small

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in an Ruby on Rails app. I use Firefox. I find that the height of the dropdown field (select tag) is too small.However the height of the text fields are appropriate. I had too add the below code to application.css to fix it:

```
select {
height: 38px !important;
}
```

Now dropdown shows its content properly though its overall height (box) is a bit bigger that text fields. Is there a neater way to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in a jsfiddle.net? I've never came across this issue with Bootstrap before. The default inputs and selects generally match up.

Answer (score 1):

I found it more appropriate to remove styling from application.scss and modify the app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss instead. custom.css.scss is generated by Bootstrap. The padding for all FORM elements was set to 10px in that file. I set padding for SELECT element to 2px and left the rest intact.